# node js creating csv file with multiple sheets

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm using `fast-csv` library in order to create a CSV file from my data.

It there a way to create a CSV file with 2 sheets (pages) from node.js?

I would also like to name each sheet.

I wasn't able to find how to do so in the documentation.

EDIT:
Is there a way to create 2 tables in one CSV file?

Comment: CSV is a plain text format (comma separated values). While you can open them in Excel and the likes, they are not spreadsheet documents so you cannot have sheets in them.

Comment: And is there a way to create 2 tables in one CSV file?